# Javascript copy to clipboard multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add the ability to click on text inside table elements and copy it to the clipboard. I have got it working however it only works on the first element on the page.

The code is as follows:

```js
const td = document.querySelector("td");

td.onclick = function() {
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.clipboardData) {
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
    console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
  }
});
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

If Data 1 is clicked it is copied to the clipboard as expected however the other elements (in this example Data 2 and Data 3) do not copy.

Using document.querySelector only gets the first element so I think that maybe my main problem but using document.querySelectorAll breaks everything.

There are different amounts of td elements on each page so I can't set a number on the amount of elements it may need to work on.

What's the best way to go about fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to select all the `td` elements, like so: `document.querySelectorAll("td");`

Then you need to iterate over them all:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => {...});
```

This gives us something like this:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```